# keeping <view> as root node in android XML file?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to Android i was going through the different possible root elements in the android XML file 
view group elements are easier to understand when kept as root elements
but how are individual views kept as root elements and how do they work exactly?
For example if i put radiobutton as the root element or a checkbox??

can anyone explain this with an example?

i googled this question, didnt get a satisfactory answer 
so i posted it here so that it would be of good use to others as well

Comment: you asked - can you create custom element with custom xml file (for example custom radiobutton)? yes?

Comment: No i meant having a view(for eg radio button) as a root element
i did not understand how it works

Comment: so why it is need and what is it root element for you?

Comment: i am just asking how it will work if i keep a view as a root element
based on your explaination i may use it for smething or stick to a viewgroup

Comment: can some one please answer this?